# Vue.JS, Staggered Transitions, and Loading More

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The VueJS Guide has a really neat approach for using the items index to create a delayed transition for the items within the dataset - [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Staggering-List-Transitions). This works super well if your data set isn't changing, but in my case I'm using a `load more` button to fetch the next set of records and add them to my array. Because the loading delay is based on `index`, the new items are not animating right away - they're waiting for the existing items to animate before they begin. Does anyone have ideas on a clean way to reset the timer between calls?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Pass correct `key` attribute.** You are probably making AJAX request to the API server when user press *Load More* button. In most cases, every element in the response will have a unique ID of the item.
   Consider:

```js
[
  { id: 15, title: 'Page #15' },
  { id: 16, title: 'Page #16' },
  { id: 17, title: 'Page #17' }
]
```

As you can see - unique property here is `id`. You should use it as `:key` in `v-for`.

```html
<span v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" class="list-item">
  {{ item }}
</span>
```

2. **Correctly change the array**. Use `array.push()`, `array.splice()` or replace the array. There is an official way to handle it:
   https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection
3. **Make sure CSS animation is correct**.

*Please, provide some code next time you ask for help. Because it's really hard to find the issue without code.*